# Create multipe functions inside a function dynamically

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm trying to write a chart function with this pattern https://bl.ocks.org/rcmoore38/9f2908455355c0589619. I intend to offer a lot more options aside from `width`, `height`, `margin` and `stroke`, but it's getting too tedious.

Since most of the code is repetitive, how can I simplify it to make the outer function more concise, can I create the inner functions (chart methods) dynamically for each option (closure variable)?

```
function drawChart() { 
  var width, height, margin, stroke;
  function chart() {
    // draw chart
  }
  chart.width = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = value;
    return chart;
  };
  chart.height = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
    height = value;
    return chart;
  };
  chart.margin = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return margin;
    margin = value;
    return chart;
  };
  chart.stroke = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return stroke;
    stroke = value;
    return chart;
  };
  return chart;
}
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ES8Q8Sqa ?

Comment: `if (!arguments.length)` --- and what does this condition do? Under what circumstances is it truthy?

Comment: in `chart.width = function(value) {if (!arguments.length)...`, the `arguments` object is bound to the inner function, but in `chart.width = (value) => {if (!arguments.length)...` it is bound to the outer function and is NOT testing for presence of `value` argument at all - see [Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_arguments)

Comment: @zerkms This actually looks feasible. But I'm wondering if I can keep everything inside drawChart() function

Comment: @ZizhangAi I edited your question so other people can find it when searching for similar problem, but if you don't like it, please revert my edit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does not provide a mechanism to access closure variables dynamically like you could access `window` properties. You can move them into a single object though:

```js
function drawChart() { 
  var props = {
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
    margin: undefined,
    stroke: undefined
  }
  function chart() {
    // draw chart
    // use props.width instead of just width
    console.log(props)
  }
  Object.keys(props).forEach((p) => {
    chart[p] = function(value) {
      // getter when called without arguments, e.g. drawChart().width()
      // setter when called with a value, e.g. drawChart().width(0)
      if (!arguments.length) {
        return props[p]
      }
      props[p] = value
      return chart
    }
  })
  return chart;
}

var x = drawChart().width(3).height(4)
var y = drawChart().height(5)

x()
y()
```